# Can't Upgrade from 16.04.3 to 17.10 (Could not calculate the upgrade)

Tags: 16.04, package-management, upgrade, 17.10

Linux kernel: **4.14.0-041400-generic**

Main log **/var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log**:

```
2017-12-02 19:12:17,716 INFO Using config files '['./DistUpgrade.cfg.xenial']'
2017-12-02 19:12:17,716 INFO uname information: 'Linux ubuH 4.14.0-041400-generic #201711122031 SMP Sun Nov 12 20:32:29 UTC 2017 x86_64'
2017-12-02 19:12:18,057 INFO apt version: '1.2.24'
2017-12-02 19:12:18,058 INFO python version: '3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]'
2017-12-02 19:12:18,061 INFO release-upgrader version '17.04.10' started
2017-12-02 19:12:18,069 INFO locale: 'en_US' 'UTF-8'
2017-12-02 19:12:18,074 INFO screen could not be run
2017-12-02 19:12:18,273 DEBUG Using 'DistUpgradeViewText' view
2017-12-02 19:12:18,320 DEBUG aufsOptionsAndEnvironmentSetup()
2017-12-02 19:12:19,320 DEBUG using '/tmp/upgrade-rw-rdow79j0' as aufs_rw_dir
2017-12-02 19:12:18,320 DEBUG using '/tmp/upgrade-chroot-o37oumea' as aufs chroot dir
2017-12-02 19:12:18,320 DEBUG enable dpkg --force-overwrite
2017-12-02 19:12:18,360 DEBUG creating statefile: '/var/log/dist-upgrade/apt-clone_system_state.tar.gz'
2017-12-02 19:12:25,153 DEBUG lsb-release: 'xenial'
2017-12-02 19:12:25,154 DEBUG _pythonSymlinkCheck run
2017-12-02 19:12:25,193 DEBUG openCache()
2017-12-02 19:12:25,193 DEBUG No such plugin directory: ./plugins
2017-12-02 19:12:25,193 DEBUG plugins for condition 'PreCacheOpen' are '[]'
2017-12-02 19:12:25,193 DEBUG plugins for condition 'zestyPreCacheOpen' are '[]'
2017-12-02 19:12:25,193 DEBUG plugins for condition 'from_xenialPreCacheOpen' are '[]'
2017-12-02 19:12:25,193 DEBUG quirks: running PreCacheOpen
2017-12-02 19:12:25,193 DEBUG running Quirks.PreCacheOpen
2017-12-02 19:12:25,709 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 86270
2017-12-02 19:12:25,709 DEBUG need_server_mode(): run in 'desktop' mode, (because of pkg 'ubuntu-desktop')
2017-12-02 19:12:25,709 DEBUG checkViewDepends()
2017-12-02 19:12:25,709 DEBUG running doUpdate() (showErrors=False)
2017-12-02 19:12:36,815 DEBUG openCache()
2017-12-02 19:12:37,295 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 86270
2017-12-02 19:12:37,295 DEBUG doPostInitialUpdate
2017-12-02 19:12:37,295 DEBUG plugins for condition 'PostInitialUpdate' are '[]'
2017-12-02 19:12:37,295 DEBUG plugins for condition 'zestyPostInitialUpdate' are '[]'
2017-12-02 19:12:37,295 DEBUG plugins for condition 'from_xenialPostInitialUpdate' are '[]'
2017-12-02 19:12:39,525 DEBUG MetaPkgs: ubuntu-desktop
2017-12-02 19:12:45,755 DEBUG Foreign: atom cassandra docker-ce google-chrome-stable kodi kodi-bin kodi-pvr-iptvsimple libcec4 libcrossguid1 libgtkd-3-0 libp8-platform2 libphobos2-ldc71 libshairplay0 libuv1 libvted-3-0 mosquitto plexmediaserver sbt tilix tilix-common tor-browser ubuntu-xboxdrv vim-common vim-gnome vim-gtk vim-gtk3 vim-gui-common vim-runtime virtualbox-5.2 wine wine1.8 wine1.8-amd64 wine1.8-i386:i386 xxd yarn
2017-12-02 19:12:45,755 DEBUG Obsolete: 4kvideodownloader 4kyoutubetomp3 gir1.2-vte-2.90 gitkraken lantern libgcrypt11 libgcrypt11:i386 libgif5 libglew1.10 libgnutls-deb0-28 libvpx1 libvte-2.90-9 libvte-2.90-common linux-headers-4.14.0-041400 linux-headers-4.14.0-041400-generic linux-image-3.19.0-64-generic linux-image-4.14.0-041400-generic linux-image-4.2.0-41-generic linux-image-extra-3.19.0-64-generic linux-image-extra-4.2.0-41-generic linux-signed-image-3.19.0-64-generic oracle-java8-installer rto-proxy steam-launcher systemd-manager ubuntu-tweak viber
2017-12-02 19:12:45,755 DEBUG updateSourcesList()
2017-12-02 19:12:45,871 DEBUG rewriteSourcesList() with mirror_check
2017-12-02 19:12:45,871 DEBUG ['ubuntu-minimal', 'ubuntu-standard']
2017-12-02 19:12:45,871 DEBUG Checking pkg: ubuntu-minimal
2017-12-02 19:12:45,872 DEBUG Checking pkg: ubuntu-standard
2017-12-02 19:12:45,875 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted'
2017-12-02 19:12:45,876 DEBUG entry 'deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty main restricted' updated to new dist
2017-12-02 19:12:45,876 DEBUG examining: 'deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted'
2017-12-02 19:12:45,876 DEBUG entry 'deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty main restricted' updated to new dist
2017-12-02 19:12:45,876 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted'
2017-12-02 19:12:45,876 DEBUG entry 'deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-updates main restricted' updated to new dist
2017-12-02 19:12:45,876 DEBUG examining: 'deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted'
2017-12-02 19:12:45,876 DEBUG entry 'deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-updates main restricted' updated to new dist
2017-12-02 19:12:45,876 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe'
2017-12-02 19:12:45,876 DEBUG entry 'deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty universe' updated to new dist
2017-12-02 19:12:45,876 DEBUG examining: 'deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe'
2017-12-02 19:12:45,876 DEBUG entry 'deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty universe' updated to new dist
2017-12-02 19:12:45,876 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe'
2017-12-02 19:12:45,877 DEBUG entry 'deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-updates universe' updated to new dist
2017-12-02 19:12:45,877 DEBUG examining: 'deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe'
2017-12-02 19:12:45,877 DEBUG entry 'deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-updates universe' updated to new dist
2017-12-02 19:12:45,877 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse'
2017-12-02 19:12:45,877 DEBUG entry 'deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty multiverse' updated to new dist
2017-12-02 19:12:45,877 DEBUG examining: 'deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse'
2017-12-02 19:12:45,877 DEBUG entry 'deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty multiverse' updated to new dist
2017-12-02 19:12:45,877 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse'
2017-12-02 19:12:45,877 DEBUG entry 'deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-updates multiverse' updated to new dist
2017-12-02 19:12:45,877 DEBUG examining: 'deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse'
2017-12-02 19:12:45,877 DEBUG entry 'deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-updates multiverse' updated to new dist
2017-12-02 19:12:45,877 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse'
2017-12-02 19:12:45,877 DEBUG entry 'deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-backports main restricted universe multiverse' updated to new dist
2017-12-02 19:12:45,877 DEBUG examining: 'deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse'
2017-12-02 19:12:45,877 DEBUG entry 'deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-backports main restricted universe multiverse' updated to new dist
2017-12-02 19:12:45,878 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted'
2017-12-02 19:12:45,878 DEBUG entry 'deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-security main restricted' updated to new dist
2017-12-02 19:12:45,878 DEBUG examining: 'deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted'
2017-12-02 19:12:45,878 DEBUG entry 'deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-security main restricted' updated to new dist
2017-12-02 19:12:45,878 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security universe'
2017-12-02 19:12:45,878 DEBUG entry 'deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-security universe' updated to new dist
2017-12-02 19:12:45,878 DEBUG examining: 'deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security universe'
2017-12-02 19:12:45,878 DEBUG entry 'deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-security universe' updated to new dist
2017-12-02 19:12:45,878 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security multiverse'
2017-12-02 19:12:45,878 DEBUG entry 'deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-security multiverse' updated to new dist
2017-12-02 19:12:45,878 DEBUG examining: 'deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security multiverse'
2017-12-02 19:12:45,878 DEBUG entry 'deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-security multiverse' updated to new dist
2017-12-02 19:12:45,878 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian xenial contrib'
2017-12-02 19:12:45,879 DEBUG entry '# deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian zesty contrib # disabled on upgrade to zesty' was disabled (unknown mirror)
2017-12-02 19:12:45,879 DEBUG examining: 'deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial stable'
2017-12-02 19:12:45,880 DEBUG entry '# deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty stable # disabled on upgrade to zesty' was disabled (unknown mirror)
2017-12-02 19:12:45,880 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian wily contrib'
2017-12-02 19:12:45,881 DEBUG entry '# deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian wily contrib # disabled on upgrade to zesty' was disabled (unknown mirror)
2017-12-02 19:12:45,881 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/tor-browser/ubuntu xenial main'
2017-12-02 19:12:45,882 DEBUG entry '# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/tor-browser/ubuntu zesty main # disabled on upgrade to zesty' was disabled (unknown mirror)
2017-12-02 19:12:45,882 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/nixnote/nixnote2-daily/ubuntu xenial main'
2017-12-02 19:12:45,883 DEBUG entry '# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/nixnote/nixnote2-daily/ubuntu zesty main # disabled on upgrade to zesty' was disabled (unknown mirror)
2017-12-02 19:12:45,883 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/neovim-ppa/stable/ubuntu xenial main'
2017-12-02 19:12:45,884 DEBUG entry '# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/neovim-ppa/stable/ubuntu zesty main # disabled on upgrade to zesty' was disabled (unknown mirror)
2017-12-02 19:12:45,884 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/rael-gc/ubuntu-xboxdrv/ubuntu xenial main'
2017-12-02 19:12:45,885 DEBUG entry '# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/rael-gc/ubuntu-xboxdrv/ubuntu zesty main # disabled on upgrade to zesty' was disabled (unknown mirror)
2017-12-02 19:12:45,885 DEBUG examining: 'deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main'
2017-12-02 19:12:45,886 DEBUG entry '# deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main # disabled on upgrade to zesty' was disabled (unknown mirror)
2017-12-02 19:12:45,886 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu xenial main'
2017-12-02 19:12:45,887 DEBUG entry '# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu zesty main # disabled on upgrade to zesty' was disabled (unknown mirror)
2017-12-02 19:12:45,887 DEBUG examining: 'deb https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian /'
2017-12-02 19:12:45,888 DEBUG entry '# deb https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian / # disabled on upgrade to zesty' was disabled (unknown mirror)
2017-12-02 19:12:45,888 DEBUG examining: 'deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-xenial main'
2017-12-02 19:12:45,889 DEBUG entry '# deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-xenial main # disabled on upgrade to zesty' was disabled (unknown mirror)
2017-12-02 19:12:45,890 DEBUG examining: 'deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main'
2017-12-02 19:12:45,890 DEBUG entry '# deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main # disabled on upgrade to zesty' was disabled (unknown mirror)
2017-12-02 19:12:45,891 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu xenial main'
2017-12-02 19:12:45,891 DEBUG entry '# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu zesty main # disabled on upgrade to zesty' was disabled (unknown mirror)
2017-12-02 19:12:45,892 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/mosquitto-dev/mosquitto-ppa/ubuntu xenial main'
2017-12-02 19:12:45,892 DEBUG entry '# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/mosquitto-dev/mosquitto-ppa/ubuntu zesty main # disabled on upgrade to zesty' was disabled (unknown mirror)
2017-12-02 19:12:45,893 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu xenial main'
2017-12-02 19:12:45,894 DEBUG entry '# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu zesty main # disabled on upgrade to zesty' was disabled (unknown mirror)
2017-12-02 19:12:45,894 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/pi-rho/dev/ubuntu xenial main'
2017-12-02 19:12:45,894 DEBUG entry '# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/pi-rho/dev/ubuntu zesty main # disabled on upgrade to zesty' was disabled (unknown mirror)
2017-12-02 19:12:45,895 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/debian 310x main'
2017-12-02 19:12:45,896 DEBUG entry '# deb http://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/debian 310x main # disabled on upgrade to zesty' was disabled (unknown mirror)
2017-12-02 19:12:45,896 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/atom/ubuntu xenial main'
2017-12-02 19:12:45,897 DEBUG entry '# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/atom/ubuntu zesty main # disabled on upgrade to zesty' was disabled (unknown mirror)
2017-12-02 19:12:45,897 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/terminix/ubuntu xenial main'
2017-12-02 19:12:45,898 DEBUG entry '# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/terminix/ubuntu zesty main # disabled on upgrade to zesty' was disabled (unknown mirror)
2017-12-02 19:12:45,898 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://shell.ninthgate.se/packages/debian jessie main'
2017-12-02 19:12:45,899 DEBUG entry '# deb http://shell.ninthgate.se/packages/debian jessie main # disabled on upgrade to zesty' was disabled (unknown mirror)
2017-12-02 19:12:45,899 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/ppa/ubuntu xenial main # disabled on upgrade to wily disabled on upgrade to xenial'
2017-12-02 19:12:45,900 DEBUG entry '# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/ppa/ubuntu zesty main # disabled on upgrade to wily disabled on upgrade to xenial disabled on upgrade to zesty' was disabled (unknown mirror)
2017-12-02 19:13:02,999 DEBUG running doUpdate() (showErrors=True)
2017-12-02 19:16:05,669 DEBUG openCache()
2017-12-02 19:16:05,670 DEBUG failed to SystemUnLock() (E:Not locked) 
2017-12-02 19:16:06,159 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 87752
2017-12-02 19:16:06,159 DEBUG need_server_mode(): run in 'desktop' mode, (because of pkg 'ubuntu-desktop')
2017-12-02 19:16:08,181 DEBUG Running KeepInstalledSection rules
2017-12-02 19:16:09,355 DEBUG Kernel uname: '4.14.0-041400-generic' 
2017-12-02 19:16:09,390 DEBUG nvidiaUpdate()
2017-12-02 19:16:10,935 INFO no old nvidia driver installed, installing no new
2017-12-02 19:16:10,936 DEBUG Removing 'xscreensaver' (ubuntu-desktop PostUpgradeRemove rule)
2017-12-02 19:16:10,936 DEBUG Removing 'gnome-cups-manager' (ubuntu-desktop PostUpgradeRemove rule)
2017-12-02 19:16:10,936 DEBUG Removing 'powermanagement-interface' (ubuntu-desktop PostUpgradeRemove rule)
2017-12-02 19:16:10,936 DEBUG Removing 'deskbar-applet' (ubuntu-desktop PostUpgradeRemove rule)
2017-12-02 19:16:10,936 DEBUG Removing 'nautilus-cd-burner' (ubuntu-desktop PostUpgradeRemove rule)
2017-12-02 19:16:10,937 DEBUG plugins for condition 'PostDistUpgradeCache' are '[]'
2017-12-02 19:16:10,937 DEBUG plugins for condition 'zestyPostDistUpgradeCache' are '[]'
2017-12-02 19:16:10,937 DEBUG plugins for condition 'from_xenialPostDistUpgradeCache' are '[]'
2017-12-02 19:16:10,937 DEBUG quirks: running PostDistUpgradeCache
2017-12-02 19:16:10,937 DEBUG running Quirks.PostDistUpgradeCache
2017-12-02 19:16:11,534 DEBUG Comparing 3.19.0-64 with 
2017-12-02 19:16:11,535 DEBUG Comparing 4.10.0-40 with 3.19.0-64
2017-12-02 19:16:11,535 DEBUG Comparing 4.14.0-041400 with 4.10.0-40
2017-12-02 19:16:11,535 DEBUG Comparing 4.2.0-41 with 4.14.0-041400
2017-12-02 19:16:11,535 DEBUG Comparing 4.4.0-101 with 4.14.0-041400
2017-12-02 19:16:11,535 DEBUG Comparing 4.4.0-28 with 4.14.0-041400
2017-12-02 19:16:12,072 ERROR Dist-upgrade failed: 'E:Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.'
2017-12-02 19:16:12,073 DEBUG abort called
2017-12-02 19:16:12,077 DEBUG openCache()
2017-12-02 19:16:12,077 DEBUG failed to SystemUnLock() (E:Not locked) 
2017-12-02 19:16:14,255 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 86270
```

Broken packages:

```
Broken libdouble-conversion1:amd64 Breaks on libdouble-conversion1v5 [ amd64 ] < 2.0.1-3ubuntu2 > ( libs )
Broken systemd-sysv:amd64 Conflicts on systemd-shim [ amd64 ] < 9-1bzr4ubuntu1 > ( admin )
Broken libpeas-1.0-0:amd64 Conflicts on libpeas-1.0-0-python3loader [ amd64 ] < 1.16.0-1ubuntu2 > ( libs )
Broken pulseaudio:amd64 Conflicts on pulseaudio-module-x11 [ amd64 ] < 1:8.0-0ubuntu3.4 > ( sound ) (< 1:9.0-2)
Broken aptdaemon:amd64 Breaks on python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat [ amd64 ] < 1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu14 > ( python )
Broken libwebkitgtk-3.0-0:amd64 Breaks on libwebkitgtk-3.0-common [ amd64 ] < 2.4.11-0ubuntu0.1 > ( libs ) (< 2.4.11-2~)
Broken imagemagick-6-common:amd64 Breaks on libmagickcore-6.q16-2 [ amd64 ] < 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.9 > ( libs ) (< 8:6.9.6.2+dfsg-3~)
Broken libabw-0.1-1:amd64 Conflicts on libabw-0.1-1v5 [ amd64 ] < 0.1.1-2ubuntu2 > ( libs )
Broken libopencv-highgui2.4-deb0:amd64 Conflicts on libopencv-highgui2.4v5 [ amd64 ] < 2.4.9.1+dfsg-1.5ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken kactivitymanagerd:amd64 Breaks on kactivities [ amd64 ] < 5.18.0-0ubuntu1 > ( libs ) (< 5.20~)
Broken gnome-software:amd64 Depends on packagekit [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.1.5-2ubuntu1 > ( admin ) (>= 1.1.4)
Broken grilo-plugins-0.3-base:amd64 Breaks on grilo-plugins-0.2-base [ amd64 ] < 0.2.17-0ubuntu2 > ( libs )
Broken gnome-software-plugin-snap:amd64 Depends on gnome-software [ amd64 ] < 3.20.5-0ubuntu0.16.04.6 -> 3.22.7-0ubuntu3.17.04.7 > ( gnome ) (= 3.22.7-0ubuntu3.17.04.7)
Broken python3-xapian:amd64 Conflicts on python3-xapian1.3 [ amd64 ] < 1.3.4-0ubuntu1 > ( python )
Broken ubuntu-software:amd64 Depends on gnome-software [ amd64 ] < 3.20.5-0ubuntu0.16.04.6 -> 3.22.7-0ubuntu3.17.04.7 > ( gnome ) (>= 3.22.7-0ubuntu3.17.04.7)
Broken unity8-desktop-session:amd64 Depends on packagekit [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.1.5-2ubuntu1 > ( admin )
Broken perl-modules-5.22:amd64 Conflicts on perl-modules [ amd64 ] < none ->  | 5.20.2-6ubuntu0.2 > ( perl )
Broken libmagickwand-6.q16-2:amd64 Depends on libmagickcore-6.q16-2 [ amd64 ] < 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.9 > ( libs ) (>= 8:6.8.9.9)
Broken packagekit-tools:amd64 Depends on packagekit [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.1.5-2ubuntu1 > ( admin ) (= 1.1.5-2ubuntu1)
Broken libconfuse0:amd64 Depends on libconfuse-common [ amd64 ] < 2.7-5 -> 3.0+dfsg-2 > ( universe/libs ) (= 2.7-5)
Broken xserver-xorg-video-mga:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-20 [ amd64 ] < none ->  > ( none )
Broken libnss3-nssdb:amd64 Depends on libnss3 [ amd64 ] < 2:3.28.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 -> 2:3.28.4-0ubuntu0.17.04.3 > ( libs ) (= 2:3.28.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.3)
Broken libmagickcore-6.q16-2-extra:amd64 Depends on libmagickcore-6.q16-2 [ amd64 ] < 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.9 > ( libs ) (>= 8:6.8.9.9)
Broken appmenu-qt5:amd64 Depends on qtbase-abi-5-5-1 [ amd64 ] < none ->  > ( none )
Broken libdata-alias-perl:amd64 Depends on perlapi-5.22.1 [ amd64 ] < none ->  > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse:amd64 Depends on xorg-input-abi-22 [ amd64 ] < none ->  > ( none )
Broken libmetacity-private3a:amd64 Depends on metacity-common [ amd64 ] < 1:3.18.7-0ubuntu0.3 -> 1:3.24.0-2ubuntu1 > ( misc ) (= 1:3.18.7-0ubuntu0.3)
Broken xserver-xorg-video-cirrus:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-20 [ amd64 ] < none ->  > ( none )
Broken libperl5.22:amd64 Depends on perl-modules-5.22 [ amd64 ] < 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.2 > ( perl ) (>= 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.2)
Broken perl-modules-5.22:amd64 Conflicts on perl-modules [ amd64 ] < none ->  | 5.20.2-6ubuntu0.2 > ( perl )
Broken libperl5.22:amd64 Depends on perl-modules-5.22 [ amd64 ] < 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.2 > ( perl ) (>= 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.2)
Broken perl-modules-5.22:amd64 Conflicts on perl-modules [ amd64 ] < none ->  | 5.20.2-6ubuntu0.2 > ( perl )
Broken libperl5.22:amd64 Depends on perl-modules-5.22 [ amd64 ] < 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.2 > ( perl ) (>= 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.2)
Broken vim-gtk:amd64 Depends on libperl5.22 [ amd64 ] < 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.2 > ( libs ) (>= 5.22.1)
Broken vim-gtk3:amd64 Depends on libperl5.22 [ amd64 ] < 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.2 > ( libs ) (>= 5.22.1)
Broken vim-gnome:amd64 Depends on vim-gtk3 [ amd64 ] < 2:8.0.0134-1ubuntu1~ppa1~x > ( editors )
Broken ubuntu-minimal:amd64 Depends on vim-tiny [ amd64 ] < none -> 2:8.0.0095-1ubuntu3 > ( editors )
```

What packages I need to remove/update/install

Comment: Did you do a thorough update and dist-upgrade before doing the upgrade?

Comment: Is this `4.14.0-041400-generic` your current kernel?

Comment: Debugging failing or failed upgrades takes longer than a fresh install. I see the errors. The only suggestion I have is to disable all those ppa and 3rd party repositories, then upgrade, then re enable repos.

Comment: I recommend to stay on 16.04 LTS (!). Do you have any serious reason for upgrade? 17.10 is a testbed of GNOME with Wayland, it is full of problems.

Comment: Are you trying to upgrade with do-release-upgrade? Skipping releases is unsupported this way. You also seem to have a lot of core packages installed from PPAs., which is more likely to result in upgrade problems as you are seeing.

Comment: @N0rbert 17.10 is far from a testbed of Gnome with Wayland, Fedora has been the test bed for Gnome on Wayland , lol . There are other changes to 17.10 and, alternates DE to gnome on wayland (such as gnome on X), and , to be honest, 17.10 is as smooth as any release. You can not avoid all the changes 17.10 brings forever =)

Comment: @Panther I'm just wondering why OP needs to upgrade stable LTS 5-years-supported release to a new 9-month-supported one. I understand that 18.04 LTS is approaching. I known other DEs, from which MATE is my favorite. Let the OP decide.